# How to treat diseases and bugs on peach tree?

Tags: diseases, bugs, peaches

I have a young peach tree (18 months old, never gave fruits) in my yard in Florida that recently lost all its leaves. The leaves are eaten but also covered with brown spots. I'm wondering if the issue is caused by bugs, or a disease, or both, and how I should treat them.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Peach trees are deciduous and lose their leaves in the winter, so don't worry about that. The leaves can turn gold/brown before they drop. Some munched leaves on a healthy tree are not a problem.

Hopefully you have a tree that requires very few chilling hours to produce, if it was purchased locally you should be okay. It is very young, but you should get a few peaches this year. It does look like it might be starting to bloom. You will get blooms before new leaf growth.

Just keep the tree pruned, watered and fertilized as recommended, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like beetle damage to me. Beetles will sometimes not chew the veins.